# Pointers and Reference issue in LuaJIT FFI

Tags: c++, c, lua, ffi, luajit

I have this function (written in C++ here):

```
GameSession *theSession = NULL;
...
...
startSesion(&theSession)
```

I have managed to get this running properly using the LuaJIT FFI here:

```
local session = ffi.new("GameSession*[1]", {})
myDLL.startSession(session))
```

However, I now need this function in LuaJIT (written in C++ here):

```
setTimeout(theSession, 3000);
```

How can this be achived in LuaJIT? Basically how can I declare theSession* from theSession** using the FFI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [FFI Tutorial](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html), you dereference pointers like this:

```
theSession[0];
```